# Mongoose is installed, but I get the error "Cannot Find Module Mongoose"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm including mongoose into my Node.js project, but when I start my server I get this error: `Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:611:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaredmoats/Desktop/Web-Development/courses/full-stack-react/models/User.js:1:80)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaredmoats/Desktop/Web-Development/courses/full-stack-react/server/index.js:5:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
```

This confuses me, because I mongoose was successfully working on this project a couple weeks ago. It has suddenly decided not to work.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

EDIT:

Here's my index.js.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const keys = require("./config/keys");
require("./services/passport");
require("../models/User");

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

console.log(keys.mongoURI);

//generate a new express application
const app = express();

//Call the exported function in authRoutes immediately after it's required.
require("./routes/authRoutes")(app);

//dyanamically figure out what port to listen to (for heroku)
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//tell express to start listening on assigned port
app.listen(PORT);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you include the 'index.js'?

Comment: @Shreyas Sure thing. Is there an easy way to do that? (I'm new to Stack Overflow). Should I just do a codepen?

Comment: Welcome to SO.

you can do that...or easier would be to 'edit' your question to add few start lines of the code from 'index'.js' in the question itself.

Comment: @Shreyas I didn't see the edit button! Thanks. I just added my index.js

Comment: maybe the key to mongoose is causing the issue. try re-generating the keys to connect.

Comment: please also include, also try to remove `npm_modules` and run `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install -g npm@latest
npm i core-util-is
```